# How can I force SQL Server Management Studio to update the IntelliSense cache?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, metadata, intellisense

IntelliSense in SSMS isn't updating unless I shut it down and restart. I've tried disconnecting from the server and reconnecting while the SSMS session is active, but that isn't working.

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a table
2. Select something from that table
3. SSMS displays
   squiggly red lines under it with the tip "invalid object name"
4. Execute the query

How can I force IntelliSense to update without restarting SSMS?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to use this key combination:

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Alternatively, use the menu item:

> Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache

This article might also be useful (for future readers who have more perplexing IntelliSense issues):

- [Troubleshooting IntelliSense in SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/)

Comment: Is there an Intellisense file that can be manually deleted to force SSMS to rebuild?